# Error in solving $x'(t) = tx(t)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$x'(t) = tx(t)^2$$

WolframAlpha gives me $x(t)=-\frac 2 {a+t^2}$. But I get:

$$\begin{align}
\frac {x'(t)}{x(t)^2} &= t \\
           \frac{d}{dt}-\frac {1}{3x(t)^3} &= t \\
\int_{t_0}^t (-\frac {1}{3x(s)^3})' ds &= t - t_0 \\
-\frac {1}{3x(t)^3} + \frac {1}{3x(t_0)^3}&=t-t_0 \\
x(t)&=\left (\frac {1}{x(t_0)^3} - 3(t - t_0)\right )^{-\frac 1 3}
\end{align}$$

Where the initial division by $x(t)^2$ is justified because only the trivia, identically zero solution is ever zero.

Comment: Not an answer, but how do you know this last statement about $x(t) \not= 0$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(-\frac{1}{3x(t)^3}\right) = \frac{x'(t)}{x(t)^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you integrate, you need to integrate also the right-hand side. So instead of $t$ you will have $\frac{1}{2}t^2$.

Additionally you made also a mistake on the left-hand side, the integral of $\frac{x'}{x^2}$ is not $\frac{1}{3x^3}$ but $\frac{1}{x}$.

If this does not help let me know and I'll type out a full solution.

Comment: Not the main error, but an error nevertheless, yes.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it must have been something stupid.

Comment: @Did: You are right, I was just editing in the other error.